# Scaling vectors in an animated vector field

Tags: plotting, animation

I want to animate a `VectorPlot3D`. But, *Mathematica* rescales the vectors in every frame. Can you scale them all to one fix point? For example, scale the vectors on their length compared to, say, the length of 10?

#### Edit

Example code:

```
 f[x_, y_, z_, g_, m_,v_] := 
   {((x)^2 - m), x*y,x*z}*(g*v^2)/
     (2*(g^2*((x)^2 - m)^2 + (v*y)^2 + (v*z)^2)^(3/2));   
plots = 
  Table[
    Show[
      VectorPlot3D[
        f[x, y, z, 1, e, 1], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
        VectorColorFunction -> Hue]], 
    {e, -5, 5, 1}];
ListAnimate[plots];
Export["Test.avi", plots, ImageResolution -> 200]
```

I want the size of the vectors to be relative to some fixed value , say 10, in every frame

---

Hi there and thank you,

some example code would be like

```
 f[x_, y_, z_, g_, m_,v_] := {((x)^2 - m), x*y,x*z}*(g*v^2)/(2*
                              (g^2*((x)^2 - m)^2 + (v*y)^2 + (v*z)^2)^(3/2));   
plots = Table[
   Show[VectorPlot3D[
     f[x, y, z, 1, e, 1], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, VectorColorFunction -> Hue]], {e, -5, 5, 1}];
ListAnimate[plots];
Export["Test.avi", plots, 
 ImageResolution -> 200]
```

and i want the size of the Vectors to be relative to some fixed value e.g. 10 in every frame

Comment: Max, show some of your code (a minimal working example would be best), so that we can reproduce what you see and start helping you out.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please add to your question the portion of you code that is causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
Manipulate[
  VectorPlot3D[{a x, y, z}, 
  {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  VectorScale -> {Large, Automatic, Sqrt[#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2 ] &}],
 {a, 0, 1, .1}]
```